# Cannot Read Property CSS of Undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var random;
var squareArray = [$('#square1'),$('#square2'),$('#square3'),$('#square4')];
var randomOrder = [];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

function computerPlays() {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    randomOrder.push(random);
    makeSquareBlink();
    userPlays();
}

function makeSquareBlink() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var randomSquare = squareArray[randomOrder[i]];
        randomSquare.css('opacity', '0.5');
        setTimeout(function() {
            randomSquare.css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
        i++;
        if (i < randomOrder.length) 
            makeSquareBlink();
    }, 500);
}

function userPlays() {
    $('#square1').on('click', function() {
        if (randomOrder[j] === 0) {
            $('#square1').css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#square1').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 300);
        }
        else {  
            $('#counter').text('!!');
            makeSquareBlink();
        }
    });
    $('#square2').on('click', function() {
        if (randomOrder[j] === 1) {
            $('#square2').css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#square2').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 300);
        }
        else {  
            $('#counter').text('!!');
            makeSquareBlink();
        }
    });
    $('#square3').on('click', function() {
        if (randomOrder[j] === 2) {
            $('#square3').css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#square3').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 300);
        }
        else {  
            $('#counter').text('!!');
            makeSquareBlink();
        }
    });
    $('#square4').on('click', function() {
        if (randomOrder[j] === 3) {
            $('#square4').css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#square4').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 300);
        }
        else {  
            $('#counter').text('!!');
            makeSquareBlink();
        }
    });
}

function reset() {
    randomOrder = [];
    i = 0;
}

$('button').click(function() {
    reset();
    computerPlays();
});
```

Why it isn't possible to change the css property of randomSquare variable in makeSquareBlink function? Is there any way to do it? Edit #001: Added the full code now Still not working help. Man stackoverflow wants more details wth should I type more ? FTHISS hit FML Fk everything letme post it bro. YOu're my last hope ://

Comment: Can you show the code where `computerPlays()` function is invoked? Share the compete code

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/5mbLjce2/. Could you edit the question to show a working sample of the issue in a snippet

Comment: Posted full code all!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Check now!

Comment: @Satpal YUP Shared it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the goal of the game is to click the same square like the computer before. Right?

One problem with your code is that `makeSquareBlink()` increases `i` by one when the computer plays. Then when the user plays and hits the wrong square inside `makeSquareBlink()` you try to access `randomOrder[i]` which is in fact calling `randomOrder[1]` which returns `undefined` as `randomOrder` only contains one element so far. Thus `squareArray[randomOrder[1]]` gives back `undefined` and `undefined.css(...)` is the error you get.

You may fix it by adding a param to your `makeSquareBlink()` method so that it reads

```
function makeSquareBlink(p) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var randomSquare = squareArray[randomOrder[p]];
        randomSquare.css('opacity', '0.5');
        setTimeout(function() {
            randomSquare.css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
        p++;
        if (p < randomOrder.length) 
            makeSquareBlink(p);
    }, 500);
}
```

And then inside `computerPlays` you call it with `i` as param and inside `userPlays` with `j`. Haven't tested it but I don't want to solve your homework completely ;)

Also rethink the event listener attachment inside `userPlays()` as this will attach click listeners each time the method is called. I guess that's not what you want. Maybe try jQuerys `one()` method here. Or better restructure your code so that the click-listeners are attached only once.

BTW here a fiddle that helped me debug your code: https://jsfiddle.net/hm69ff0a/